# Storing serialized data in a SQL Server XML / string column with DataTable and DataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, serialization, datatable

I wonder if someone can help me thru this scenario:

In SQL Server, I have a column of type `XML` or `string` . My application has a serializable data object which I want to store in that column.

The `DataColumn` in my `DataTable` has the type of this object. But when I try to update my database I get the exception

> No mapping exists from object type […] to a known managed provider native type

This is actually clear, but is there a way to inject a converter / mapper doing this typed serialization and deserialization while `Fill` and `Update` using `DataAdapter`?

[Edit]
[image: This shall be the data flow]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: Whatever you are writing, if this is still in development phase, please take a step back and avoid storing XML data in SQL Server. SQL Server is extremely good for reading writing normalised data but extremely poor dealing with XML data. The performance of XML shredding in SQL server is extremely poor and slow. Shred your XML in your application layer and store data in SQL Server tables in columns.

Comment: @M.Ali your view is a good point, but even if the database column is type of string, I still like to convert the data from or to the destination type.

Comment: @M.Ali, There are situations, and quite often, when a programmer does not have the right to change the database structure, but he is allowed to record information about objects in the form of a string formatted in xml code. In such situations, when the structure of objects changes dynamically, the xml format of the field in the table is best suited.

Comment: @ValeriyTito your comment is a typical Dev response to a DB person's recommendation, and I do appreciate that sometimes going with an XML doc does seem like a good option. But if you are using SQL Server, then sticking to best practices for SQL Server will get you far but if you dont, it will hurt in the long run :) If dynamic nature of the data is really a concern then make use of document db but trying to use SQL Server like a document db will only result in more problems :)

Comment: I just gave an example of when it has been impossible to "take a step back" for many years. Because architecture has been around for 5 years, and you came only a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do that. My column definition in the SQL Server table is:

```
[FileData] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
```

The Dataset in my app is defined like this, a string:

[image]

Comment: So your conversion does take place when using the data in the application, doesn't it? This comes close to this  `row[columns.Criteria.Name] = entry.Values.Serialize();`  What I try to achieve is converting the data when filling or updating the data set

Comment: My "conversion" is: .FileData = tables_Values_DS.GetXml

Comment: For my purpose this is "too much" and "too late".  In my example in the comment above I want to store `row[columns.Criteria.Name] = entry.Values;`. The conversion should take place when call `Update()` on the adapter

Comment: There are datatable events you might be able to use to achieve this, to intercept the changes, but I don't think you're going to have a easy time of it - especially going between the same table/adapter.

Answer (score 0):

An Exception

> No mapping exists from object type […] to a known managed provider native type

appears when you forget to serialize an object when working with an xml column.
Here is an example of the correct approach when working with xml type fields

```
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Sale_T(SaleID, SaleInfo) values(@SaleId, @SaleInfo);";
    cnn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
    {
        Sale saleInfo = new Sale
        {
            Client = "Thomas",
            SaleDate = DateTime.Now,
            Items = new List<Product> {
                new Product { ProductName = "Apple", Price = 1.5 },
                new Product { ProductName = "Orange", Price = 0.8 } }
        };
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleId", 2);
        // An attempt to directly assign an object leads to System.ArgumentException "No mapping exists from object type Sale to a known managed provider native type."
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleInfo", saleInfo);
        // you have to pre-serialize

        var Ser2String = (Sale si) =>  { 
            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sale));
            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                mySerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, si);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        };

        string serSale = Ser2String(saleInfo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleInfo", serSale);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

OK, here's the continuation of the story, only now using

```
void DataAdapterFillExample(){
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Sale_T", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    string saleID = row["SaleID"].ToString();
                    // here you can add desSerialization
                    string saleInfo = row["SaleInfo"].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{saleID} | {saleInfo}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:

> 1 | Peter0001-01-01T00:00:00Apple1.5Orange0.8
> 2 | Thomas2023-01-23T18:01:50.4545511+03:00Apple1.5Orange0.8

Comment: this works with `ExecuteNonQuery`. I am looking for adding a converter using `dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)` & `dataAdapter.Update(dataTable)`

Comment: OK, here's the continuation of the story, only now using dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)

Comment: This still converts the data after the data was loaded into the DataTable

Comment: I think in this case it would be right for you to show the code that does not work.

Comment: there is no code yet. But what we conclude is, that there is no convinient way to modifiy (convert) the data between 'DataTable' and the SQL Server. So what I have to do is move convertion outsite the datatable as you stated in your post